# VBA Selenium: Selecting a button behind multiple div tags

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I was using selenium with VBA and there is the current webpage. I was trying to get the bot to select the "exportbutton" ID, but I have already tried Findelementbyxpath etc., and the error is always returned saying it cannot locate that ID. It looks like the button is behind multiple divs and I am not sure how to select it. I have already looked through for iframes and there are none present in the webpage. How can I select this button behind this header.

Button Snapshot:

[image: HTML Code]

Answer (score 0):

The *`<button>`* element have the *id*, *class* and *tittle* attributes.

```
<button id="exportbtn" class="button2" title="Save the report in a file (pdf, excel, ...)">
```

---

### Solution

To click on the element you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using *FindElementByCss*:

  ```
  d.FindElementByCss("button#exportbtn[title='Save the report in a file (pdf, excel, ...)'] > span").click
  ```
- Using *FindElementByXPath*:

  ```
  d.FindElementByXPath("//button[@id='exportbtn' and @title='Save the report in a file (pdf, excel, ...)']/span").click
  ```

Comment: This isnt working :( Im still getting the error saying it cant be found.